# Writing to Internal Storage - Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException

Tags: android, android-file, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to save a class object to internal storage, so I don't have to use `SharedPreferences`. However, the file I am trying to save to cannot be found.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

    final String filename = "userInfo.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), filename);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Fblogin(){ //Called when user tries to login with Facebook
        //Off-topic FB code here
        new User(/*args*/){
            @Override
            public void userFinished(User user){

            try{
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(user);
                objectOutputStream.flush();
                objectOutputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e){e.prinstacktrace();}

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to manually create the file myself and put it into my project folder, or does the `createNewFile()` accomplish that for me?

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: userInfo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at com.couponwallet.couponwalletconsumer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:124)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
```

Edit: I somehow mixed up my two activities and it is my other activity that has the problem. This `try catch` is in my `MainActivity` in the `onCreate`.

```
try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("userInfo.txt"));
        /*Above line is line 124 and causes the error*/
        user = (User) ois.readObject();

        Log.v("MainUser", "try statement");

        if (user == null) {
            Log.v("MainUser", "null");
        } else {
            Log.v("MainUser", user.toString());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please add more lines from exception - still can't determine what particular line of code raises the exception. Later on stacktrace must be reference to your code.

Comment: You don't need `createNewFile()`. `openOutputStream()` alone is sufficient. However, the error does not line up with your code. The error would suggest that you had `new File(filename)` and were trying to work with that.

Comment: Added to the exception.